# How do I submit a form using HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I want my program to go on several sites and post to the forms. How can I accomplish this in HttpWebrequest?

Comment: your not making a spam-bot are you? :)

Comment: Your question is very broad and sounds like you want us to write the program for yourself. If you have a more specific question, try asking that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP request with post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty easy to find with a quick [search](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=c+post+webrequest+example#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=c%23+post+webrequest+example&pbx=1&oq=c%23+post+webrequest+example&aq=f&aqi=g-j1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2900l2900l0l3579l1l1l0l0l0l0l244l244l2-1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=fdbe5bcf5e3c173e&biw=1680&bih=946).

[HttpRequest example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) and [WebClient example](http://technet.rapaport.com/Info/LotUpload/SampleCode/Full_Example.aspx)